# How to build and upload code in Arduino if I'm using shared library?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-yun

I have a C code I want to embed with Arduino `.ino`, this code using some shared library (`.so`) present in current working directory. How can I build and upload this code to my `Arduino Yun` using Arduino IDE (or any other method).

If I'm doing it the hard way, please suggest what's the right thing to do here.

Comment: no os in arduino? then i guess it's impossible if for arbitrary .so

Comment: get the lib sources  and do a static build

Comment: You first need to implement a Linux (or whatever OS the lib was built for) emulator on Arduino. After that things will become much easier and you will have lots of time to have some coffee.

Comment: @Ôrel that looks good idea.

Comment: @Olaf well I think it would require a lot of caffeine to do that too.

Comment: Since Arduino does not support shared libraries (you are building a firmware, after all) I don't think that your .so is compiled for arduino (or for atmel uP). So.. Your binary code is not compatible with your platform: you need to compile it again: get the sources and include them in your arduino environment as @Ôrel suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use `Bridge` to access Linux side of Arduino Yun you're using and run `bash` or `python` or even C using `yun-gcc` programs. This will help you embedding shared (`.so`) libraries for C and importing other libraries also to expand your scope you're working on. Good luck!"

Comment: there is an OS in Arduino Yun named Linino (OpenWRT distribution)